# How to extend viewport to the full screen width?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a .body element on my page http://crimeansurfers.tumblr.com which has a border frame that should touch the edges of the screen.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arquitecta', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: ;
    border: #00f 10px solid;
    background: url(https://secure.static.tumblr.com/nu04jpk/IgAniz800/grid_lyfe_background.gif) #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It shows up fine on desktop (the frame touches the edges of the screen, however, when I open it on a mobile, it shows like this:

[image]

As you can see, the right frame is not touching the edge of the screen, but it's supposed to.

I'm using also `viewport` to resize display for mobile devices with the following parameters:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">`

What do I need to change in order for it to work as I intended it to?

Thank you!

**UPD** maybe it makes sense to render the frame using some other method rather than `body` CSS tag?

Comment: Try to add `width: 100vw` in body element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overflow being caused by the `ul` element within the `#thumbs` div.
You can fix this by adding a media query to the bottom of your style sheet.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 414px) {
  #thumbs ul {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

In this case I've set a max width of the media query to 414px as the problem only shows on screen sizes smaller than iPhone 6+.

Comment: Seems right, but I had to add zero to make it work: `padding-left: 0;` Thank you!

Comment: @deemeetree ahh apologies have fixed the typo